# How to use Fetch API data in Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

how to fetch data from MongoDB using redux and how does it send data to multiple pages. how can i set the state to check the data is fetch from redux.

Comment: You can't fetch data directly from mongoDb. You have to query an api witch queries the database. You typically do that when dispatching an action.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete code snippet :

```
const initialState = {
  allData: [],
};

// Your API Fetch Here
export const fetchData = createAsyncThunk("data/fetchData", async()=>{
  const response = await fetch("http://www.api.com/api")
      .then(res=>res.json())
  return response;
})

export const serviceSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'dataName',
  initialState,
  // The `reducers` field lets us define reducers and generate associated actions
  reducers: {
    
  },

  extraReducers: (builder) => {
      // data goes into state
    builder.addCase(fetchData.pending, (state) => {
        state.status = 'loading';
      })
    builder.addCase(fetchData.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.status = 'idle';
        state.allData.push(action.payload) ;
      });
  },
});
```